# Third Person Perspective Camera with Opengl

Tags: java, opengl, camera

I want to implement a TPP Camera for my project, but something is not working + i don't know if i use the right concept.

Should I rotate the whole scene model-view matrices except my main model, which will be centered on the screen or rotate the lookAt camera?

Other thing is how to make the model move in given direction after rotating? (I think moving the whole scene makes it easier?) + how to add collision detection to it?

Answer (score 1):

Collision detection is nothing to do with openGL you use you game state variables to work that out you can manage it in the same loop as the game where you do user input and display.

You should use a LookAtMatrix for the third person camera you will have the eye component behind the player and the at somewhere infront. Persective can be implemented by using a [perspective matrix](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tut04%20The%20Matrix%20Has%20You.html).

So the matrix multiplication will look like.

PerspectiveMatrix * LookAtMatrix * worldSpacePosition

Here is a good answer from gamedev explaining a [lookatmatrix](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/8845), most OpenGL / Computer Graphics books will also cover this.

Are you working with the new or old pipeline model?

Comment: I use opengl3 but with a provided framework by my lecturer. I use the lookAt camera which i initiate by: `MatrixMath.lookAt(this.eyeX,this.eyeY,this.eyeZ,this.at,this.up);`

but when I try to rotate it changing eyeX or eyeZ it doesn't rotate but move along the axis, ex. decrementing X will rotate a bit, but the the camera goes further and further away... (hope i exaplained my issue properly)

Comment: That lookAt function is missing the At component. Does that even compile?

Comment: `this.at`, which is set earlier. it compiles without a problem no worries

Comment: Sorry I didn't have my glasses on when reading your comment, I just noticed that there wasnt as many arguments as I would have expected. I seems odd that the function takes 3 floats and 2 vectors.

Comment: `public static Mat4 lookAt(Vec4 eye, Vec4 at, Vec4 up) {



        final Vec4 eyeneg = eye.neg();


        final Vec4 n = VectorMath.normalize(eye.sub(at));


        final Vec4 u = VectorMath.normalize(VectorMath.cross(up, n));


        final Vec4 v = VectorMath.normalize(VectorMath.cross(n, u));


        final Vec4 t = new Vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);


        final Mat4 c = new Mat4(u, v, n, t);


        return c.mul(MatrixMath.translate(eyeneg));


    }`

Comment: the problem is i cant rotate the camera properly 360 when i want to rotate the character